# How can I read /etc/config.d/... with python?

Tags: python, configuration-files

I want distros to pick up my python app so they can make a /etc/myapp config file and a /etc/myapp.d/ folder, where users can put their configs over overwrite settings in /etc/myapp.

It should support the following (more or less standard) configuration style.

```
# settingx does ...
settingx=1

settingy = 0

settingz = "--this x --that y"
```

And in my python app I want to use settingx, settingy etc.

What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ConfigParser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) as this is an accepted settings exchange format that is baked into the python distribution.

```
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()

config.add_section('myapp')
config.set('myapp', 'settingx', 1)
config.set('myapp', 'settingy ', 0)
config.set('myapp', 'settingz ', '--this x --that y')

# Writing our configuration file to 'example.cfg'
with open('/etc/myapp/example.cfg', 'wb') as configfile:
    config.write(configfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use an `RPM` for distributing your app have a look at this - http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package

Alternatively have a look at [distutils](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/index.html#distutils-index)

If you plan to simply have some sort of install script, then it can create the file and directory itself.